# Rails keeps displaying home page on root even when I delete the method in the Pages Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is more of a question than a real issue, but I created a new rails project. I've changed the

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/contact'

  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

and my Pages controller looks like this

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home]

  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

My homepage gets displayed even if I remove the home method.
I just wanted to know more about how this works.

I've looked around before posting and couldn't find an answer.
This is my first post here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious if my answer was helpful?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot ! Sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Rails 'convention over configuration' mantra. See [Rendering by Default: Convention Over Configuration in Action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

From the guide:

> By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to valid routes.

So, even if the `home` action is undefined, Rails will still render the `home` view because there is a valid route.